# $('body').on('click', '.anything', function(){}) not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

```
$('body').on('click', '.anything', function(){})
```

vs

```
$('.anything').click($.proxy(function(event) {});
```

I'm able to perform click function using `$('body').on('click', '.anything', function(){})` in **android** device but the same is not working in **iOS** device. Actually I'm using cordova to develop my application

Comment: Are `.anything` elements added after the code above?

Answer (score 5):

It seems on iOS, click events are not generated if the browser does not encounter an officially clickable element. So for example `A` tags always generate click events, while the `body` or `div`s may not.

An workaround is to set the CSS rule `cursor: pointer;` which works for at least some elements.

So you may try

```
body{
     cursor: pointer;
}
```

or

```
.anything{
     cursor: pointer;
}
```

in your CSS and see if it triggers then.

Comment: I try your solution  but still no changes reflect.

Comment: Also check my comment on the question above. And maybe you can put an jsFiddle online of some part of your page which shows the problem, otherwise there may be several not-so-common reasons.

Comment: Yes I checked my code on  jsFiddle online and its working and as I mentioned in my question that the code is working on android but when I'm running the same code on IOS (javascript, html and css code is same in both cases) then at that time it doesn't work.

Comment: Would you share the fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use touch events for web applications. Because touch events are faster than click event.

Try:

```
$('body').on('touchend', '.anything', function(){
   console.log('don\'t touch this. too do do do');
})
```

Comment: Yes, this is the solution even in 2022 on all mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `ontouchend` do not use `onclick`. `onclick` can not work on some android devices.

Answer (score 0):

I inset a WKWebView on my iOS app. 
I monitor js method on WKWebView Delegate.

It can't work the following way :

```
$('body').on('click', '#div', function(){})
```

It can work the following way :

```
$('#div').click(function(event) {});
```

==========================================

ps: 
Method 1：

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="test3.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('button').click(function() {
      console.log("It worked");
   });
   $('.test').html('<button>Test</button>');
});
```

Here we are attaching the .click method to the button, but if you look at the html the button does not exist yet so we are attaching the .click method to an inexistent element. The button element would then be added to the .test class, but it would not have the .click method bound to it. So if you did load this page and tried to click on the test button it would not do anything.

Method 2：

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="test3.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', 'button', function() {
        console.log("It worked");
    });
    $('.test').html('<button>Test</button>');
});
```

This would log out “It worked”.

Answer (score 0):

Not my solution, but it works great ...

```
$(function() {

    // Check if it is iOS
    var isiOS = (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false);

    if(isiOS === true) {

        // Store -webkit-tap-highlight-color as this gets set to rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) in the next part of the code
        var tempCSS = $('a').css('-webkit-tap-highlight-color');

        $('body').css('cursor', 'pointer')                                    // Make iOS honour the click event on body
                 .css('-webkit-tap-highlight-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)');     // Stops content flashing when body is clicked

        // Re-apply cached CSS
        $('a').css('-webkit-tap-highlight-color', tempCSS);

    }

});
```